# SOLVED: Magento 1.9 ignores config from default scope

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration

The Magento shop of a new customer (I didn't set up the store, I was brought into the project as a developer) was recently infected with the magentocore.net skimming malware. I removed it from the database, secured the installation and so on.

A lot of configuration in the backend was done previously in the default scope. Most of the entries in core_config_data belong to that scope. However, this configuration is now ignored by Magento.

One concrete example:
- In the default scope, the locale options where set to timezone W. Europe and Locale to German.

- In the frontend, the language shown is english.
- I switched the configuration scope to the website and store, but in both cases, "use default" was selected.
- but normally, when "use default" is selected, the correct value from the default scope is shown
- this wasn't the case. Instead there was "AUS..." (the first option) as timezone and "Afrikaans" as locale.

The options from the default scope are getting ignored, in the backend and the frontend as well.

As a short fix, I changed a few options in the website scope.

What I don't understand is, why all of these options are getting ignored. Any pointers or ideas would be really appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into a similar problem here.

Comment: In fact I did. Here is the solution: The shop was affected by the magecore attack. The attacker / the malware wrote an entry with the path "general" and value NULL into the core_config_data table. That caused the problems. All keys from general were ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Check file local.xml , maybe someone change it , and all default are ignored

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136688)

Comment: Why not ?? Lol    if you dont know that is that file , pls go to the next topic..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: The shop was affected by the magecore attack. The attacker / the malware wrote an entry with the path "general" and value NULL into the core_config_data table. That caused the problems. All keys from general were ignored.